# Brasero will not blank my DVD, CD-RWs

Tags: dvd, burning, cd-image

Using Ubuntu 12.10 and I can't erase any of my DVD, or CD-RWs. Terminal will not  work either. I have tried all the force commands in terminal and nothing. The DVD is recognized as a rewritable disk so I don't know why its not working.  When I open Brasero I have no "menu" to choose blanking from.

The data on the disk that I want  to blank has some backup from Windows 7 is that why Brasero will not blank it? I no longer have Windows 7, Ubuntu is my only OS.

I want to put Linux Mint on this DVD.

Comment: It could be faulty media, try another disc. If that fails try install/use K3b, it is much more capable than Brasero.

Comment: My suggestions in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178797/cant-format-dvdrw-disk) might help if you haven't tried similar things already.

Answer (score 5):

I am the developer of libburn which probably does the drive
related stuff for your Brasero.

In order to distinguish between a problem of Brasero's own
code and a problem of libburn, you could use one of my
command line applications of libburn called xorriso. This can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install xorriso
```

as it does not automatically get installed with `libburn4` on Ubuntu.

A blank command would be (I assume your drive has address `/dev/sr0`):

```
xorriso -outdev /dev/sr0 -blank as_needed
```

Then obtain the state of drive and medium:

```
xorriso -outdev /dev/sr0 -toc
```

In case of success, xorriso should then report among other lines

```
Media status: is blank
```

If this succeeds, then Brasero's code is to blame, resp. the
system facilities by which it gets information about drive and
medium. (I cannot help with such problems.)

If above command fails to blank the medium, then you will have to
show me the messages of the blank attempt and the outcome of -toc run.
Probably we will have to obtain a log of the commands sent to the
drive and the replies which are received:

```
xorriso -scsi_log on -report_about ALL -outdev /dev/sr0 -blank as_needed 2>&1 | tee -i /tmp/xorriso.log
```

The log will be quite verbose. Thus above command catches a copy in
file `/tmp/xorriso.log`. This file would then of interest for me.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas

Comment: xorriso is a useful tool- I was not very familiar with it before, but the man page is very interesting reading.

Comment: Always a good time when the author of the software is there to answer questions about it. Looks like my DVD is to blame. According to the command, "Media is not of erasable type"